# How to create key-value svg images in readme.md file?

Tags: github, markdown

How to create such svg images?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://shields.io/, as described in [`alexandresanlim/Badges4-README.md-Profile`](https://github.com/alexandresanlim/Badges4-README.md-Profile), in order to add any badge you need.

For a project README, you can "[add a workflow status badge](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge)", or use another action like [`actions/dynamic-badges`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dynamic-badges) in order to display the right value and color for a given service:

[image: badges]

The idea behind using a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) is to update those badge automatically during a build, after for instance [a push to your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push).